# How can I delete a temporary voice channel when everyone disconnects?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made code such that if someone connects to a particular channel, the bot will create a channel with their name and then move them in it. I want the bot to auto-delete the channel when this user disconnects and no one else connects to this channel. I have this code but I don't know how to delete the channel.

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) =>{
    let mainCatagory = '604259561536225298';
    let mainChannel = '614954752693764119';
    if(newMember.voiceChannelID === mainChannel){
        newMember.guild.createChannel(`${newMember.user.username}'s Channel`,'voice')
        .then(temporary => {
            temporary.setParent(mainCatagory)
            .then(() => newMember.setVoiceChannel(temporary.id))
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.error(err);
        })
    }
});
```

I tried to do `if(newMember.voiceChannel.members.size === 0){temporary.detele};` but `temporary` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array to write the ID of the temporary channel and the server on which this channel was created, in front of the body of the event.

```
 var temporary = []

 bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) =>{
     const mainCatagory = '604259561536225298';
     const mainChannel = '614954752693764119';

     if(newMember.voiceChannelID == mainChannel){
        // Create channel...
         await newMember.guild.createChannel(`${newMember.user.username}'s channel`, {type: 'voice', parent: mainCatagory})
             .then(async channel => {
                 temporary.push({ newID: channel.id, guild: channel.guild })
                 // A new element has been added to temporary array!
                 await newMember.setVoiceChannel(channel.id)
             })
     }

     if(temporary.length >= 0) for(let i = 0; i < temporary.length; i++) {
         // Finding...
         let ch = temporary[i].guild.channels.find(x => x.id == temporary[i].newID)
         // Channel Found!         
         if(ch.members.size <= 0){

             await ch.delete()
             // Channel has been deleted!
             return temporary.splice(i, 1)
         }
     }
 })
```

Comment: but he doesn't delete the channel only create it.

Comment: @BrokenSoul try replacing `temporary.push({ newID: channel.id, guild: channel.guild })` with `temporary.push({ newID: channel.id, guild: newMember.guild.id })` and also replace `let ch = temporary[i].guild.channels.find(x => x.id == temporary[i].newID)` with `let ch = bot.guilds.find(x => x.id === temporary[i].guild).channels.find(x => x.id === temporary[i].newID)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining an empty variable first, like `temp` and then assign it the temporary channel when returning the `createChannel()` promise, like so:

```
 bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) =>{
        let mainCatagory = '604259561536225298';
        let mainChannel = '614954752693764119';
        let temp;
        if(newMember.voiceChannelID === mainChannel){
            newMember.guild.createChannel(`${newMember.user.username}'s Channel`,'voice')
            .then(temporary => {
                temp = temporary
                temporary.setParent(mainCatagory)
                .then(() => newMember.setVoiceChannel(temporary.id))
            }).catch(err =>{
                console.error(err);
            })
        }
        if(newMember.voiceChannel.members.size === 0){temp.delete()};
    });
```

Comment: Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined`

Comment: try ``if(oldMember.voiceChannel.members.size === 0){temp.delete()}`` instead? Since it's not a new member. Be careful though, you should probably add the condition that the channel is a temporary one because otherwise it'll delete any empty channel i think

Comment: and i tried `oldMember`. Error:  `temp.delete()` => `delete` not defined, becuase temp is `undefined`.

Comment: get rid of ``temp`` and try ``if(oldMember.voiceChannel.members.size === 0){oldMember.voiceChannel.delete()};`` Same warning as before

Comment: How delete temp works? :( How can i get id of temporary channel to delete it?

Comment: i meant get rid of it litterally, instead of using ``let temp`` and ``temp = temporary``, just change you last if statement to ``if(oldMember.voiceChannel.members.size === 0){oldMember.voiceChannel.delete()};``, temp was undefined before because it's a promise, which you can't actually store like that, but it wouldn't have worked anyway because of logical reasons i hadn't noticed before

Comment: Sorry @Francois i really tried but can't understand that, Can you do it for me please.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have time for that :) But if you want to understand how to do it i'd suggest you read documentation on objects, functions and promises and try to apply what you learn to discord.js

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [Raifyks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618634/8289918), but updated for Discord.js v12/v13 and has a few improvements.

```js
const mainCategory = '604259561536225298';
const mainChannel = '614954752693764119';

// A set that will contain the IDs of the temporary channels created.
/** @type {Set<import('discord.js').Snowflake>} */
const temporaryChannels = new Set();

bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
    try {
        const {channelID: oldChannelId, channel: oldChannel} = oldVoiceState;
        const {channelID: newChannelId, guild, member} = newVoiceState;

        // Create the temporary channel
        if (newChannelId === mainChannel) {
            // Create the temporary voice channel.
            // Note that you can set the parent of the channel in the
            // createChannel call, without having to set the parent in a
            // separate request to Discord's API.
            const channel = await guild.channels.create(
                `${member.user.username}'s channel`,
                {type: 'voice', parent: mainCategory}
            );
            // Add the channel id to the array of temporary channel ids.
            temporaryChannels.add(channel.id);
            // Move the member to the new channel.
            await newVoiceState.setChannel(channel);
        }

        // Remove empty temporary channels
        if (
            // Is the channel empty? (thanks to Rakshith B S for pointing this out)
            !oldChannel.members.size &&
            // Did the user come from a temporary channel?
            temporaryChannels.has(oldChannelId) &&
            // Did the user change channels or leave the temporary channel?
            oldChannelId !== newChannelId
        ) {
            // Delete the channel
            await oldChannel.delete();
            // Remove the channel id from the temporary channels set
            temporaryChannels.delete(oldChannelId);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```